# Cross-browser Save As .txt

Tags: javascript, save-as, execcommand, data-uri

Is there a JavaScript library that allows to save strings as txt files, and works cross-browser?

In the past, I have been using Downloadify, but I am looking at another option for a couple reasons:

- I hope to find a pure JavaScript solution, without the need for Flash
- it seems that Downloadify is not updated anymore
  (no update in the past 18 months)
- I am experiencing an issue with Downloadify in IE 9, where strings are cut off

Comment: The short answer: no. Longer answer: Plugins, signed javascript. Cross browser: not without flash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way is to use data: URLs to force a download:

```
var data = "This is a test";
window.location.href = "data:application/x-download;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
```

Two catches here:

- It won't work in MSIE because its support of data: URLs is very limited (supposedly [for security reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). So you will still need Downloadify there.
- You cannot specify a file name, the suggested file name will depend on the browser used. And file type will be "unknown" (you cannot use a known MIME type because the browser won't offer to download the file then).

Bonus reading: there was a W3.org discussion in February 2010 on fixing the second problem: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2010Feb/thread.html#msg58. However, this doesn't seem to have made it into any specification so far, let alone browser implementations.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) what you need. But it's not cross-browser yet. Works in Google Chrome.

```
<a download="MyFile.txt" 
   href="your-data-uri-here"
   draggable="true" 
   class="dragout"
>Download ready</a>
```

Also Wikipedia has a good [article about Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 0):

[FileSaver API](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) is cross-browser compatible

```
var text = "Hello, world!";
var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "filename.txt");
```