# How to save an image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm working on a Chrome Extension: when you drag an image, it will be saved to your computer.
I learned that in HTML5 there is FileWriter API, but really can't find any example of it, and does Chrome support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a FileWriter API in HTML5. What you probably mean is the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) that allows you to *read* files. And in Chrome even extensions aren't allowed to write files, for reasons of security. So unless you want to bundle an NPAPI plugin with your extension (which would trigger a huge warning upon installation) all you can do is trigger a download message that the user might choose to accept - or not. See [Cross-browser Save As .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464828/cross-browser-save-as-txt/6465780#6465780) for a possible approach (Flash objects like Downloadify being the other).

**Edit**: I was wrong, there is a FileWriter API proposal. It is very far from being done however.

Answer (score 2):

I found this. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/
You can find some examples.

**Edit** This is screenshot from the article. I'm using chrome 12.0

[FileWriter API browser support message http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/329503613.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF3XCCKACR3QDMOA&Expires=1308932374&Signature=DXBdFSjbNqaeJPr%2F0fSAqPWyh2E%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/329503613.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF3XCCKACR3QDMOA&Expires=1308932374&Signature=DXBdFSjbNqaeJPr%2F0fSAqPWyh2E%3D)

Comment: I see, there is apparently a proposal to allow read/write access to parts of user's disk contrary to what I said in my answer. This proposal is in early stages however and might never be implemented by any browser (the security questions seem still unsolved).

Comment: @Wladimir The article says the chrome and my browser(chrome) appears to support all of the functionality used in this article. I'll upload the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the FileWriter API will be ready and usable for some time yet.

You could get the image data in hex, then use a DataURI to 'export' it from the browser. Although this leads to a file saved with a filename such as "download(1)". Each browser seems to have different size limitations for DataURIs, and they're not big, although ahould be fine for a reasonably sized image.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Alternatively you could use a Downloadify to save it with a proper filename (Requires flash and may be tricky to embed into the chrome extension).

http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify