# Saving String of Data as a file with HTML5 + Javascript without using URI

Tags: javascript, file, html, save, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser Save As .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464828/cross-browser-save-as-txt)

I'm looking for a way to save a sting of data to a file only using HTML5 and Javascript, without using any server-side techniques (PHP, ASP etc..)

I'm using URI for the moment :

```
<script>
 var content = "test";
 uriContent = "data:plain/text.," + encodeURIComponent(content);
 newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'test');
</script>
```

However the browsers don't name the file with the right extension. I'm wondering is there a way to save strings without using only using HTLM5 + Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we are not there yet. There is a draft for a [FileWriter API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) but it's not implemented in most browsers.

If you can fall back to Flash you should take a look at [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).