# How do I download image dataURL by javascript. Which is generated from canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I already got a lot of ans([Ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792616/downloading-file-from-dataurl-in-javascript),[Ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)) for it but when I am trying to download it by clicking on `<a>` tag. its showing an error in Google Chrome[image]

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); 
var w = window.open('about:blank', 'image from canvas'); 
w.document.write("<a href='javascript:window.print()' >Print</a>"); 
w.document.write("<a href='"+dataURL+"'> Download</button>"); 
w.document.write("<img id='printArea' src='" + dataURL + "' alt='from canvas'/>");
```

Comment: Can you show your JS codes ?

Comment: @Raptor 27    `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

            var w = window.open('about:blank', 'image from canvas');
            w.document.write("<a href='javascript:window.print()' >Print</a>");
            w.document.write("<a href='"+dataURL+"'>  Download</button>");    
            w.document.write("<img id='printArea' src='" + dataURL + "' alt='from canvas'/>");`

Comment: post your codes in your question by **edit** feature next time.

Comment: or `window.open(dataURL);`

Comment: my data size is more than 2.5MB