# any clean ways to download files like html5 download attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fully aware that there are many debates(and solutions) out there in terms of downloading files in javascript/jQuery, such as `iFrame`, `jQueryPlugin`. However, I am more interested in a kind of built-in facilities like `download` attribute of `<a>` in HTML5. The problem is that it supports [a couple of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute):

[image]

That is how I want to download files, without creating frames or using any plugins. The questions is are there any other cross browser built-in(say, easier or cleaner) ways to do it?

- Internet Explorer 8+
- Firefox 19+
- Chrome 17+
- Safari 5.1.9+
- Opera 12.1

Comment: It is no server part, it is just client part. Question don't possible dublicate

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which has support for all modern browsers.

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), which generates and force downloads files with Flash.
There's also a [demo](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) available.

Or you could download the file using XHttpRequest ($.get in jQuery) and use [data URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464828/cross-browser-save-as-txt).