# Javascript file download not working in IE11 I have generated pdf and I want to download that generated pdf

Tags: javascript

I used download attribute to download the file. but it is not working in IE11. I want some other option to download the file in IE11.

```
a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a); 
a.style = "display: none"; 
a.href = url; 
a.download = fileName; 
a.click();
```

Comment: I used This Code // Create link.
        a = document.createElement( "a" );
        // Set link on DOM.
        document.body.appendChild( a );
        // Set link's visibility.
        a.style = "display: none";
        // Set href on link.
        a.href = url;
        // Set file name on link.
        a.download = fileName;
    
        // Trigger click of link.
        a.click();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [any clean ways to download files like html5 download attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331666/any-clean-ways-to-download-files-like-html5-download-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

`download attribute` is not support on IE11 .
For details see a link:

[developer.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/adownloadattribute/)

For alternative way see below link of old SO question.

[Any clean ways to download files like html5 download attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331666/any-clean-ways-to-download-files-like-html5-download-attribute)

FileSaver will not automatically convert your HTML to PDF. Use jsPDF for PDF creation .

jsPdf in github.

[jssPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) .

Demo [Link](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/).

Comment: I refer your Link. I that I find the filesaver.js which is help to downloading text file. but my question is, I have generated pdf and I want to download that generated pdf. please help and thanks in advance for support